# writing and then running a python file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, file, command

I have written a python code in a file (suppose file_0.py) in which I am writing a python file with incrementing index (like file_1.py). The index is read and saved in a index.txt file and incremented throughout the code.

```
import os
def write_fun_and_call():
    with open(__file__, 'r') as current_file:
        fun_str = current_file.read()
    with open("index.txt", 'r') as init_file:
        i = int(init_file.read())
    i += 1
    with open("index.txt", 'w') as init_file:
        init_file.write(str(i))

    python_file = "fun_" + str(i) + ".py"
    with open(python_file, 'w') as pyFile:
        pyFile.write(fun_str)
    # os.system("python " + python_file)
    return

write_fun_and_call()
```

My question is "if I uncomment the line (os.system) and run the code, is it safe, or some kind of memory issue will be there, also what happen if I can control the index, in that case is it ok ?"
Thanks in advance.

Comment: exec is a better way if doing this, read the strings in the file into a python string variable and then call exec(var)

Comment: That completely depends on what was in the input file; but generally speaking, no, you cannot guarantee that there is not anything bad in the file, and you should only execute code you have audited. This seems like a poor solution to every imaginable problem statement anyway, and very much like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem); what are you _actually_ hoping to achieve here?

Comment: As all previously started processes remain in memory or are moved to the (also limited) paging file there will be a memory issue if you don't stop early enough.

Comment: @tripleee Suppose there is nothing special else in the file,you can suppose it "as it is" as I mentioned here, Is it safe now if I limit the index. Well I want to visualize self
generating/reproductive systems through the python code.

Comment: The code here seems complex enough that you can perhaps achieve "not obviously unsafe" but not "obviously not unsafe". Your problem description seems rather vague but I would vaguely suggest looking for a Python sandbox or implementing your own virtual machine architecture on top of Python where you can more directly control what the generated code can access and modify.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Yes, may be , but If I control the incremental index in the code, can it could be a safe solution in this condition? What you think.

Comment: @tripleee Yes, it is good to check the situation in a virtual box operating system for safety purposes. Thanks for the suggestion,

Comment: @GautamJangid The precise number of possible generations before failure depends on other activities of the operating system and is therefore changing and not predictable.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Exactly, so I think this is very complex in current scenario. It will make system hang and other processes will be affected due to large memory uses and so the system performance will be decreased rapidly.

Answer (score -1):

No it is unsafe if app run in background,- for stop ull must do another action. If u run it from console u can press ctrl+c for stop.

```
import os
def write_fun_and_call():
    with open(__file__, 'r') as current_file:
        fun_str = current_file.read()
    with open("index.txt", 'r+') as init_file:
        i = int(init_file.read())
        i += 1
        init_file.seek(0)
        init_file.write(str(i))
        print(i)
    if i>=10: #emergency stop
        exit()        

    python_file = "fun_" + str(i) + ".py"
    with open(python_file, 'w') as pyFile:
        pyFile.write(fun_str)
    os.system("python " + python_file) #os.system(python_file) if python in systempath
    return i


print(write_fun_and_call())
'''
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
'''
```

First app will be stoped last

Comment: Have you checked it by removing comment (os.system) ?

Comment: yep, but i add `if i>=10: exit();` for stop, if i remove it, i also can stop app by ctrl+c in terminal. For realy 'unsafe' need use `os.system('at ...`

Comment: You have just stopped the code with taking condition i=10; that is not I am asking, I am actually asking that if the code can run for infinite time and we can manage the code to control it from taking large memory (either by RAM or storage) and can put some specific logic to checkout the behavior.  For example we can delete old indexed files, controlling the incremental value of i etc.

Comment: No. after some time, memory will be full, becourse first script run second .. but first script will be stop after second. After some time u'll have too much running script. For infinity u must use task manager on win, or `at` on linux or `start file` on win, i mean you need `non blocking start`

Comment: OK, can we make a solution in which first stop without stopping the second?

Comment: yep, but it need call OS function. `os.system("start " + python_file)` for windows & there are way for stop emergency- remove 'index.txt' and we'll have exeption

Comment: Great, Thanks!!. but when I use os.system('start ' + python_file) the console is showing frequently, I think we can hide this by using win API.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240015/discussion-between-gautam-jangid-and-ganz).

Comment: yes, use `os.system("start /B " + python_file)`